# Prevent Parent touchable opacity onPress if child touchable opacity is disabled

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I have a component like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={parentOnPress}>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={childOnPress} disabled={isDisabled}>
    <View><Text> Just a child </Text></View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

if `isDisabled` is `true`, and the child TouchableOpacity is clicked, then it triggers the `parentOnPress` method.

How to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Well, the disabled child is wrapped with a non-disable parent. The parent reacts to touches as expected. No issue here. Maybe you should disable parent instead of child?

Comment: But then I also need to do some operation on pressing the parent touchable opacity.